# How do I draw these syntax structure trees?

Tags: syntax, historical-linguistics, syntax-trees

I couldn't figure out how to draw the syntax tree diagrams for these sentences. Any help would be great

- Who said that John is nice?
- A teacher in my school said the children disliked him.
- What do you want to eat?

Comment: Are you looking for someone to draw the trees for you?

Comment: ya pretty much Bill. I've been trying for a long time and am still unsure. I think if I see them drawn I can learn from them

Comment: If you avoid the X-bar type (which no one likes) trees can be fairly easy.. If you give me a couple of hours, I'll put the trees up for you.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! Ya my Professor makes us do the X-Bar type and its annoying for sure

Comment: Oh ok. Yes that would still be really helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

These are the diagrams for your three sentences. 
Note the cross-referencing symbols *i* and *j* for the prenucleus items in the last tree.

Comment: In a subject-dependent inversion like "here are some tips", is the complement 'here' in prenuc with a gap, or is it just fronted. If fronted, is it a pre-head dependent of the predicator and is the subject still external to the VP?