# How to draw tree structures in Microsoft Word?

Tags: syntax, software, trees

Has anybody found an easy way of drawing tree structures in Microsoft Word? I have to do all my parsing using tables and would much prefer to draw tree structures.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about linguistics but about software, [softwarerecommendations.se] might be a place to go to.

Comment: What counts as "easy"? It's easy for me to draw trees, because I've practiced. Just point and click: and think about what you're drawing. Or do you mean "automatically converted labeled bracketing into trees"?

Comment: I do my trees in Word because there is no program I'm aware of that can give two labels (function and category) to each node. It is fiddly, especially drawing the lines, and once you've drawn it you have to send it to Paint and then save it back to your directory as a JPEG.

Comment: There must be more specialized web apps...

Comment: - Yes jknappen I wondered if it would be off-topic however people answering in the software section will not have looked for a way to draw syntax trees.

Comment: - yes Luke I was hoping somebody would answer with 'I use such and such' and then import into word

Comment: - yes Billj - you have been through the same experience as me. I'm moderating an online Ancient Egyptian class and I have to put out model answers. In the end I decided to parse using tables because I couldn't find an easy way to draw syntax trees neatly and quickly.

Comment: The end result is reasonable for uploading here on SEL: see my answer here [link](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/26372/how-do-i-draw-these-syntax-structure-trees#comment54082_26372). Elsewhere it looks much better, so I suppose its SEL's software that reduces the quality somewhat.

Comment: INSERT SHAPE is hardly easy.  It takes 5 clicks per line segment.  Scaling shapes to a consistent size is also a pain, and I've had parts of trees flip upside down when dragging into Paint.